# What does II mean in this strumming instruction?

Tags: strumming

What does the II above the numbers in the strumming section mean?

[image]

Comment: A guess is it means don't play *on* the beats 1,2,3 and 4, but only the off-beats - sort of reggae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern diagram appears to separate the count into four separations,  seeing how the up arrow is coming in on the second half of the &.

Another way to count it would be the syllables One - E - And - Uh, where on count is broken into four beats, or one quarter note separated into sixteenths.

The strumming would be coming in on the And - Uh, or back two beats of each count, or the last two sixteenths of each count, down strum on the "And", up strum on the "uh".

```
   e   +  uh    e  +  uh    e  +  uh    e  +  uh
1  .   .  .  2  .  .  .  3  .  .  .  4  .  .  .
       ↓  ↑        ↓  ↑        ↓  ↑        ↓  ↑
```

The two lines then are representing the two beats of the first half of the count.

Edit: looking at it again, I suspect the two lines are the PAUSE symbol...

Comment: Seems like they've borrowed the '**II**' sign used on recorders, for 'pause'.

Comment: That makes sense! I was searching everywhere for specific strumming symbols, but it looks like it was just the generic pause symbol XD

Answer (score 1):

Guess:

I think the II sign has to tell us that the upbeat is mute. Compare this picture: (V)

[image]